# Is TCP header a part of every IP datagram?

Tags: tcp, ip, datagram

I saw the following question :

"Suppose datagrams are limited to 1,500 bytes (including header) between source Host A and destination Host B. Assuming a 20-byte IP header and a 20-byte TCP header, how many datagrams would be required to send an MP3 consisting of 4 million bytes?"

In the solution, it is calculated as 4*10^6/1460 = 2740 approx.
Hence, it is assumed every datagram contains IP as well as TCP header.

As per my knowledge, TCP header need not be replicated in every datagram, so there will be one datagram of 1460B rest all 1480B which is giving me 2703.

4000000 - 1460= 3998540B , these should go in 1480B datagrams.

No. of 1480B datagrams = 3998540/1480 = 2702.

So total 2703.
I am confused. Please help!!

Comment: "TCP header need not be replicated in every datagram" is false. How do the receiver knows which applications should receive the packet if it doesn't contain TCP Header ?

Comment: So at the destination, when every segment is delivered to the Transport Layer and it decapsulates it, it verifies the segments correspond to the same segment by checking the tcp header?